# Modify Stripe subscription status

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been trying to modify the subscription 'status' from 'trialing' to 'active' once the user buys our standard subscription but it doesn't recognize the parameter 'status'. 
Post URL : https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_DlwSiqrLvSArgV
Request body:
`{
  "Status": "active",
  "items": {
    "0": {
      "id": "si_DlwSpUvFPN6Mje",
      "deleted": "true"
    },
    "1": {
      "plan": "plan_Dk4I92tnE0cmXS"
    }
  }
}`

Response:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: Status",
    "param": "Status",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

I'm not sure if I'm putting the status in wrong place or if i need to add some other additional parameter(s) to change the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `status` property is calculated by Stripe and it's not something you can set yourself. It is not in the list of parameters for the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) either.

If you want to move a subscription from 'trialing' to 'active' you have to explicitly end the trial period by passing `trial_end: "now"` as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-trial_end). This will automatically charge the customer the expected amount and if the charge succeeds it will switch your subscription to active at the same time.